# How retrieve discord sever stats for other peoples servers using python script?

Tags: python, api, discord, screen-scraping

Does anyone know of how I can collect the 'server stats' of all the discord severs I am joined to. I would like to create a python script that can use the server ID and automatically collect the server stats. Is it possible to do this using their API. I tried to use the API but I could only retrieve the sever messages. I also tried to use selenium to scrape the 'server stats' values but this failed as I have to log in to discord. Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_guild()` method to get the guild and access it's [properties](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-object-guild-structure).

Answer (score 0):

Servers are called 'Guilds' in the Discord API. This question is old but for anyone coming across this in the future, here's a basic rundown:

1. Get all servers for the current user agent with [`GET /users/@me/guilds`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds)
2. Using Guild IDs returned, you can access the extra info about each server of interest from [`GET /guilds/{guild.id}`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild)
3. For info on members (e.g. names, roles), use [`GET /guilds/{guild.id}/members`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members)
4. For info on channels (e.g. message_count), use [`GET /guilds/{guild.id}/channels`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-channels)
5. For info on messages (e.g. authors, timestamps), use [`GET/channels/{channel.id}/messages`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages)

The API is very well documented, so I'd recommend having a read if there's something else you'd like to access. As long as you have the correct permissions, you will be able to find the info you are looking for.

You can also integrate this easily with a python app using [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html)